# Will C++ lambda really make copies of parameters captured by copy?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization

Using a lambda function in C++ with variables captured by value implies a [copy of the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073709/does-capture-by-value-in-a-c-lambda-expression-require-the-value-to-be-copied#10074041).

With a good compiler, and assuming we do not modify the value within the lambda function, can we hope that there will be no actual copy once the code is compiled and optimized?

For example, in the following it seems to make sense to pass `new_item` as a value since it is used in read only mode.

```
void loadavg_file::add(loadavg_item const & new_item)
{
    auto const & it(std::find_if(
            f_items.begin(),
            f_items.end(),
            [new_item](auto const & item)
            {
                return (item.f_address == new_item.f_address);
            }));

    if(it == f_items.end())
    {
        f_items.push_back(it);
    }
    else
    {
        // replace existing item with new avg and timestamp
        it->f_timestamp = new_item.f_timestamp;
        it->f_avg = new_item.f_avg;
    }
}
```

Will the loop be optimized out and result in absolutely no copy of `new_item`?

Comment: There is no guarantee. A good compiler *may* optimize away the copy, but it is not required to.

Comment: The only thing you know is the code is required to behave like it did.  If there is no difference between inlining the whole thing and making no copies/object and what you wrote then the compiler could do it.  Will it? compile it and check the assembly.

Comment: This question seems more interesting to me than to the other two commenters. AFAIK, the compiler is only allowed to elide copies in certain conditions, and I don't know if lambda capture is one of them. (That doesn't matter when copies are trivial, but OP probably wouldn't care if copies were trivial.)

Comment: @zneak This really isn't about copy elision but code substitution IMHO.  The whole thing could be inline into a loop with a body.  AFAIK the as-if rule would permit that.

Comment: @NathanOliver, code substitution would still have to do a copy if copy elision isn't allowed (and if copies aren't trivial).

Comment: [gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/CdCBnM) creates a copy, have a look at the assembly (clang does as well)

Comment: @m.s. That might also be dependent on the types of `loadavg_item`'s data members. What if they're all trivial types? There's no way to say for sure whether the compiler will always create a copy or not. In any case, it's not clear to me why the OP is not capturing `new_item` by reference in the first place.

Comment: @Praetorian you are of course right, but since the OP did not supply a [mcve] I had to guess

Comment: @Praetorian, we can't tell if a compiler will always follow some optimization, but we can determine if this optimization is *at least* allowed or not. I'm absolutely willing to be swayed, but right now, it's not clear to me that it is.

Comment: @zneak Not so sure.  [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f81cb0bc6c38f799) looks like a perfectly valid way to optimize what the OP has and no copy was made or even needed to be elided.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I'm not so sure that this is a valid way to optimize the given code, precisely because you're eliding the copy that by-value capture seems to imply.

Comment: That might make this a better question if it is asked as if the compiler is allowed to take what the OP has and create that "optimized" code.  Right now the question is *will it happen* and that is harder to answer as it would need to be tested against all compilers and settings.

Comment: @NathanOliver, we can't give an authoritative "yes" for any compiler if the optimization is possible, but we can give an authoritative "no" if it's not, if someone actually goes through the trouble of verifying. By asking if a copy would be avoided "with a good compiler", the OP is essentially asking if it's allowed, not whether any specific implementation currently does it.

Comment: @zneak Well, we can go round and round with this all day, but I don't see why under the as-if rule there needs to be a copy made, or for a functor to be created from the lambda, or for a loop to exist from the `find_if` call if the compiler can determine loop unrolling makes more sense in this case, and that there is only one data member in `loadavg_item` you care about comparing against and said data member is of some trivial type.

Comment: @Praetorian, because the semantics of lambdas are to create an object that has one field per captured variable, with the implication that the fields are copy-constructed from the originals. The as-if rule allows the compiler to inline functions and unroll loops, but it doesn't allow it to discard the side effects of a copy. This is covered by copy elision rules.

Answer (score 8):

If the copy constructor of `new_item` (i.e. `loadavg_item::loadavg_item(loadavg_item const&)`) has observable effects other than allocation of memory, then those effects must be observed to occur (as long as, y'know, you actually make an effort to observe them).

This is because you might be depending on those side effects occurring, and this is not a context where copy elision is allowed; copy elision is only allowed (and, latterly, mandated) when *returning* a value from a function. On the other hand memory allocation elision is allowed anywhere (subject to the rules in **[expr.new]**/10); clang is particularly good at this.

Inspecting the generated assembly does not count as observation of side effects, and nor does running the program in a debugger.

If the copy constructor of `new_item` is non-inline, then the assembly of the translation unit might exhibit a call to the copy constructor as a symbol, but link-time optimization (LTO) can still elide that call if the link-time optimizer can deduce that the copy constructor has no observable side effects.

Comment: Would this mean that using a reference is more likely to increase the chance of getting an optimization? In other words, as C++ programmers, should we use a reference in nearly all cases for optimization purposes (unless the lambda function is really to make modifications on a copy of the object, obviously)?

Comment: @Alexis: I wouldn't phrase it that way.  A reference is guaranteed to avoid the copy, and also likely to kill other optimizations, because the compiler has to handle cases with aliasing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, <strike>a copy is</strike> two copies (because the lambda is passed by value, its members get copied again) are required for your code.

If the entire call tree (`find_if`, copy constructor, destructor, `operator==`, any functions those call) consists of visible functions and the compiler choose to inline them, it is possible that further optimizations such as common-subexpression-elimination may reduce or eliminate the runtime cost of those copies.

In the process, the compiler will have to prove that

- The value of the copy doesn't change (because such changes should not propagate to the original)
- The copy constructor has no side effects.
- The destructor has no side effects.
- None of the functions rely on the object's identity.
- The copy's lifetime cannot exceed the lifetime of the object referred to by the parameter.
- No other aliases exist for the object referred to by the parameter, or such other aliases will not be used to modify said object while the lambda is in use, including accesses from other threads (if synchronized).

If you want to avoid the copy, don't write code asking for that copy.  Or copy only the needed portion of the object, e.g.

```
auto const & it(std::find_if(
        f_items.begin(),
        f_items.end(),
        [key = new_item.f_address](auto const & item)
        {
            return (item.f_address == key);
        }));
```